Why does `callr::r_session` hang inconsistently on Windows after using `ps::ps_interrupt`?
I am confused about some callr::r_session or ps::ps_interrupt behavior, which I find difficult to enunciate. I will try to be as clear as I can through the step-by-step example below.
Suppose I have the following code in a script file called example.R:
### Region of interest starts here.

# Start a permanent session.
session <- callr::r_session$new()

# Create a cluster in the session.
session$run(function() {
    cluster <<- parallel::makeCluster(2, type = "PSOCK")
})

# Get the worker PIDs.
worker_pids <- session$run(function() {
    parallel::clusterCall(cluster, Sys.getpid)
})

# Keep the session busy (i.e., but not the workers.)
session$call(function() {
    while (TRUE) { Sys.sleep(0.1) }
})

# Allow some time for the call to kick in.
Sys.sleep(0.25)

# Interrupt the session.
session$interrupt()

# Get the state (i.e., expect `busy`).
session$get_state()

# Wait for the session to be interrupted.
if (session$get_state() == "busy" && session$poll_process(0) == "timeout") {
    # Wait.
    session$poll_process(-1)
}

# Read the interrupt result (i.e., error).
session$read()

# Get the state (i.e., expect `idle`).
session$get_state()

# Intentionally attempt to propagate the interrupt to the cluster workers.
session$call(
    function(worker_pids) {
        # Interrupt each worker process.
        lapply(
            # Worker process IDs.
            worker_pids,

            # Handle each worker process.
            function(pid) {
                tryCatch(
                    expr = {
                        # Get a process handle.
                        handle <- ps::ps_handle(pid)

                        # Interrupt the process.
                        ps::ps_interrupt(p = handle, ctrl_c = TRUE)

                        # Return some informative message.
                        return(paste0("Interrupted worker `", pid, "`."))
                    },
                    error = function(e) {
                        # Return some informative message.
                        return(paste0("Failed to interrupt worker `", pid, "`."))
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    },

    # Arguments passed from the main (e.g., interactive) session.
    args = list(worker_pids)
)

# Get the state (i.e., expect `busy`).
session$get_state()

# Wait for the session to finish with the call.
if (session$get_state() == "busy" && session$poll_process(0) == "timeout") {
    # Wait.
    session$poll_process(-1)
}

# Read the session output.
session$read()

# Get the state (i.e., expect `idle`).
session$get_state()

# Sys.sleep(0.1)

# Run something in the background session.
session$run(function() {
    print("Session `run` output.")
})

# Verify that the workers are still alive.
session$run(function() {
    parallel::clusterEvalQ(cluster, {
        print(paste0("Worker `", Sys.getpid(), "` is alive."))
    })
})

### Region of interest stops here.

# ...

# Close the session later.
session$close()

Then, if I execute the script example.R on a Unix system using
Rscript --vanilla example.R

it runs as expected. However, on Windows the script hangs either at
# Run something in the background session.
session$run(function() {
    print("Session `run` output.")
})

or
# Verify that the workers are still alive.
session$run(function() {
    parallel::clusterEvalQ(cluster, {
        print(paste0("Worker `", Sys.getpid(), "` is alive."))
    })
})

and not necessarily always. Sometimes, the first session$run where it hangs also outputs NULL.
The issue seems to be related to line ps::ps_interrupt(p = handle, ctrl_c = TRUE) because after commenting it out the script runs as expected.
I tried different things, including sending the ps::ps_interrupt signal from the main session instead of the background callr::r_session, to no avail. The only solution I found was to insert a Sys.sleep(0.1) just before the first point where the script hangs. However, this feels quite arbitrary, and I would really like to understand what is happening.
Do you have any idea what is happening?
